# How to delete temporary asp.net files at once?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, visual-studio-2010, asp.net, temporary-files

I am trying to delete temporary asp.net files from `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary`. Some ASP.NET files
and some folders get deleted but for some folders I have to open each folder and then delete them manually.

Have set the property of folder as NOT READ ONLY but still some files do not get deleted.

It is very time consuming. Is there any property I can set which can help me delete all the files/folders at once?

Comment: Just right click on the `Temporary ASP.NET` folder within `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\` and change the properties or just delete the folder.  The folder will automatically be generated.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. It says you need permission to perform this action .

Comment: - Just take ownership of the folder then proceed to delete it.

Comment: soooo much easier than it used to be under IIS6. you used to have to stop the app pool or it wouldn't let you delete anything....

Comment: Refer this https://forums.ivanti.com/s/article/How-to-clear-the-Temporary-ASP-NET-files may it helps.

Answer (score 0):

(IF you running on IIS local)
Just Stop IIS service, then you can delete all folders.

Stop IIS -> CMD -> iisreset /stop;
Start IIS -> CMD -> iisreset /start;

(IF you running on IISEXPRESS)
Close the iisexpress service, delete folders then running it back.